# ggplot legend with logs

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

I am trying to use the log of a value to fill bars in a plot, and have the fill legend to display the original value.

Example of the legend colors I would like:

```
library(data.table)
df = data.table(date=Sys.Date()+0:7,
                size=c(100,200,50,300,450,70,50,200),
                objective=c(1,2,2,2,5,2,3,1),
                actuals=c(0.8,2.5,2,2.2,4,1.8,15,0.2))
df[,deviation:=actuals/objective-1]
df[,log_deviation:=log(deviation+1)]

ggplot(df,aes(date,size,fill=log_deviation))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_gradient2(high = "tomato", low = "blue",mid = "seagreen1",labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

And the legend values I would like:

```
ggplot(df,aes(date,size,fill=deviation))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_gradient2(high = "tomato", low = "blue",mid = "seagreen1",labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Is there an elegant way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Would this work for you? `ggplot(df,aes(date,size,fill = deviation))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_gradient2(high = "tomato", low = "blue",mid = "seagreen1",labels = scales::percent, trans = "log1p")`

Comment: Yes! that's it! I had to overwrite the breaks to avoid the higher numbers overlapping with the following code, but that's it, thanks! Do you wanna answer the question so I can give you credit? breaks <- exp(seq(from = log(min(df$deviation)+1),to = log(max(df$deviation)+1),length.out = 6))-1;
ggplot(df,aes(date,size,fill = deviation))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+ 
  scale_fill_gradient2(high = "tomato", low = "blue",mid = "seagreen1",labels = scales::percent, trans = "log1p", breaks = breaks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the transformation in the scale:

```
ggplot(df,aes(date,size,fill = deviation))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_gradient2(high = "tomato", low = "blue",
    mid = "seagreen1",labels = scales::percent, 
    trans = "log1p")
```

If you don't like the default breaks, define `breaks` within the scale.